# tcpdf, fpdi setting page width and heights

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

So I have kind of a unique problem. I am using both the fpdi and tcpdf to help compile a final pdf file. The final pdf includes meta data (used via tcpdf) and importing an original pdf (used via fpdi) and some text overlay and such. Everything works great, but one small issue. The original pdf that is being imported is sized at 8.50 in x 10.88 in. But after the new pdf renders it the pdf is at 8.27 in 11.69 in.

Is there anyway I can set the width and height? Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work well.

Thanks